# MVC app, where does this logic belong?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

At work last week we had a meeting / presentation about rethinking how we do MVC, based on what's probably a lot of research by our boss and some reading into other SO questions. One takeaway for me was that when people say "separate logic from data" it would probably me more accurate to say "separate logic from your data *source*". If you do the first, you might fall prey to an anemic domain model. Am I correct in this?

Secondly we learned that MVC doesn't contain your business logic anywhere. This should be in a separate service layer or BLL apart from the web app. Reconciling these two points seems a bit tricky - does a particular piece of logic go with the data objects, as basic OOP principles dictate, or in a separate layer?

Here's a specific example that I need help with right now. I'm pretty convinced that this would belong in the service layer but I still have other questions. Let's say I have some behavior that takes as input multiple different entities of different types. It runs, and then as output, it can modify the input entities, and generate new entities as records. In my case it's for a game, but you could say it's like a transaction. There are multiple people involved, some products, and a receipt generated.

1. The easy question, where would you put this logic? Is it a separate class that gets instantiated?
2. The hard question (for me) is who is responsible for calling this code? It would feel wrong to have the controller do it. Or is that exactly its job? What if it doesn't get run on any one particular page, but whenever the user accesses the site after a particular time? Base controller?
3. In general, how do you decide between "this belongs in my entity class so that it isn't just a pile of getters and setters" and "this belongs in my service layer"? Or am I mixing things up... do the entity classes belong in the service layer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's sort out some terminology first. What you're referring to as the "service layer" is more commonly called the "Domain model", as you say, not to be confused with a MVC model. At the most basic level, the MVC model encapsulates the domain model. How the two interact isn't defined by the pattern itself but the models store states the logical way is to realise there are two different states:

- The domain state- in the real world this will more often than not be stored in a database somehow but the domain model should not expose any data source to the MVC model. This allows domain models to retain proper encapsulation. Any logic which mutates or accesses this data should be done here with relevant but abstract accessors for the MVC model to access.
- The application state- that is things like "Which record is being edited at the moment?"

To answer your question it really depends on what you are doing with the data. If you're doing any kind of processing then this should be done in the domain model. If you're just fetching collections of data which are needed for display purposes then the MVC model should query the domain model(s) to retrieve the relevant data. The view should then inquire the model for this data.

So to answer your questions:

1. In thisspecific case: The transaction which processes the data should be inside the domain model. It has direct access to all the relevant data and should just be called with any required parameters. This promotes reusability because it's not directly tied to the MVC model.
2. Technically, if your controller is accessing the domain model directly it's closer to an MVVM implementation than an MVC one. However, this is not a bad thing, provided your domain models take arguments which aren't tied to domain logic there's not real issue. However a controller should not be constructing a domain object (e.g. creating a user account and passing it to the model). The reason for having the domain model which sits outside the MVC triad is for exactly that: So that it doesn't matter what calls the code, the domain logic is agnostic to the architecture it's running in. This is a good thing. MVC is presentaitonal, sometimes domain logic is just data processing. In regard to "whenever the user accesses the site after a particular time" this is domain logic so should certainly go in the domain model. Where depends on exactly what triggers the event, but in this case it could be part of the login routine or similar.
3. Indeed. The entities (by which I'm assuming you mean objects which refer to a single domain object, a user, a product, a blog, etc?) will probably not contain much logic themselves as they are mostly data structures. An order may have a "getProducts()" or "getDeliveryAddress()" which fetches related entities but the domain model would do any processing on the data itself.

As a rule of thumb, almost any logic that mutates data or processes data that comes from multiple entities should happen in the domain model. There are two main reasons for this: 1. Reusability, that logic can be reused from anywhere. 2. Encapsulation. Once you start putting this logic inside entities you end up with a situation where domain entities have dependencies on other domain entities. This leads to very brittle code in the real world as you end up with arbitrary rules being introduced at a later date such as "These customers don't have to enter payment details". "This is a corporate customer and they don't have a billing address" if you've modelled your "Order" class to be constructed with dependencies on a set or products a user and a billing address this becomes a larger task than dealing with that at an earlier stage in the domain model.